# How can I send a value from form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 projects in 1 solution first one to log into database second one have my main project my second project 'Class Library' Output.

I am trying send User Name  from first project log in form to main project main form

I am using code

```
public string MyValue;
    {
        get { return txtUserName.Text; }
    }
```

in log in window 
and use

```
var frm1 = new DS4ERP .Core .Lanch .frmLogin ();

            radLabel2.Text = frm1.MyValue;
```

i get nothing in second form 
what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new Form instance. When you opening your second form use this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();  // change Form2 with your second Form name
f2.Show(this);
```

Then change this code:

```
var frm1 = new DS4ERP.Core.Lanch.frmLogin ();
radLabel2.Text = frm1.MyValue;
```

To:

```
 radLabel2.Text = ((frmLogin)Owner).MyValue;
```

Comment: now its working thanks :) i hope i can make your answer verified